# Input Device Identification

Tags: c++, windows, uwp, gamepad

Is there any way to identify an input device that is connected to PC? (such as gamepad, arcade stick etc)? In Xbox One SDK every device in Windows::Xbox::Input::IController has got his own ID, but Windows::Gaming::Input::IGameController don't have any id fields.
How to identify connected devices? How to determine which controller was removed and which one is still active?

Comment: You might find [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/Windows.Gaming.Input.IGameController#Windows_Gaming_Input_IGameController_UserChanged) useful. I can't say for sure but reading the `user` property or listening for and checking the data fired on `UserChanged` both seem like promising ways to go.

Comment: I tried that, but this will not work. The user id (NonRoamableId) is always the same. 
My case looks like this: I have two (or more) controllers connected to PC and when one has been disconnected I want to know which one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In UWP, we can use classes under [Windows​.Gaming​.Input Namespace](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.gaming.input) to detect and track gaming input devices. As you've added [gamepad](/questions/tagged/gamepad) tag in your question, I will use gamepad for example.

To detect and track gamepads, we can use [Gamepad Class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/Windows.Gaming.Input.Gamepad). The [Gamepad](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/Windows.Gaming.Input.Gamepad) class provides a static property, [Gamepads](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/windows.gaming.input.gamepad.gamepads.aspx), which is a read-only list of gamepads that are currently connected. Please not it is recommended that you maintain your own collection instead of accessing them through the `Gamepads` property.

Once we have the collection, we can then use [GamepadAdded](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/windows.gaming.input.gamepad.gamepadadded.aspx) and [GamepadRemoved](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/windows.gaming.input.gamepad.gamepadremoved.aspx) events to track gamepads. As their names, these two methods are raised when a gamepad is added or removed. The following is a simple sample:

```
auto myGamepads = ref new Vector<Gamepad^>();

for (auto gamepad : Gamepad::Gamepads)
{
    myGamepads->Append(gamepad);
}

Gamepad::GamepadAdded += ref new EventHandler<Gamepad^>(Platform::Object^, Gamepad^ args)
{
    myGamepads->Append(args);
}

Gamepad::GamepadRemoved += ref new EventHandler<Gamepad^>(Platform::Object^, Gamepad^ args)
{
    unsigned int indexRemoved;

    if(myGamepads->IndexOf(args, &indexRemoved))
    {
        myGamepads->RemoveAt(indexRemoved);
    }
}
```

If you want to determine which controller was removed, I think you can take advantage of the index. For more info, please see [Detect and track gamepads](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/gaming/gamepad-and-vibration#detect-and-track-gamepads).

For other gaming input devices, they are similar to gamepad, you can refer to the documents under [Input for games](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/gaming/input-for-games).